# Moving a Shape in Excel with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, shapes, do-while

I have a script that is rolling dice across the the screen.

I want to return the dice to the Center of the screen. I am trying to use a Do Wile loop but the dice keeps going. The Do-while is near the bottom of the code below.

```
Sub Roll_Dice()
Dim leftDieRotation As Single, rightDieRotation As Single, leftDieMovement As Single, rightDieMovement As Single
Dim wsCraps As Worksheet
Set wsCraps = Sheets("Craps")
With wsCraps.Shapes.Range(Array("Group 38"))
   .Left = 500
   .Top = 80
End With
 With wsCraps.Shapes.Range(Array("Group 39"))
    .Left = 500
    .Top = 180
 End With
For x = 1 To 50
   Randomize
   leftDieRotation = Int(10 + Rnd * 25)
   leftDieMovement = Int(2 + Rnd * 25)
   rightDieRotation = Int(10 + Rnd * 25)
   rightDieMovement = Int(2 + Rnd * 25)
    With wsCraps.Shapes.Range(Array("Group 38"))
    .IncrementRotation leftDieRotation
    .IncrementLeft leftDieMovement
    End With
   With wsCraps.Shapes.Range(Array("Group 39"))
    .IncrementRotation rightDieRotation
    .IncrementLeft rightDieMovement
    End With
Sheets("dice").Range("a1") = Int((6 - 1 + 1) * Rnd + 1)
Sheets("dice").Range("e1") = Int((6 - 1 + 1) * Rnd + 1)
DoEvents
Next x
' move dice to center
Do While wsCraps.Shapes.Range(Array("Group 39")).Left >= 500
    With wsCraps.Shapes.Range(Array("Group 38"))
    .IncrementLeft -5
    DoEvents
    End With
Loop
End Sub
```

Basically I can't seem to test the `Do While wsCraps.Shapes.Range(Array("Group 39")).Left >= 500`.
Both of the dice roll just fine. They stop on the far right of the screen ( I may be submitting a second Question to determine how to gauge the width of the screen.)
Then 1 Dice starts to move to the left. But instead of it stop moving once it gets around the 500 mark, it just keeps going all the way to the left side of the screen.

Comment: Why does the loop refer to 39 but the movement is applied to 38?

Comment: Because I am old and have bad eyes and was tired and only looked at that 27 times.   That was the issue.  Thank you so much!  Hopefully, others will be able to use some of the code to assist in their project.